# dev_appserver.py doesn't recognize my files

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to get a basic GAE tutorial to work with Windows 7.

So far I have:

1. Installed python 2.5.4
2. Installed the current GAE SDK
3. Set my PATH varible to include python and the GAE
4. Created a "hello, world" app with an app.yaml and main.py file as specified.

When I call `dev_appserver.py .` in my app's directory or `dev_appserver.py DIRECTORY_NAME` one directory above my app, I receive the error message:

> Invalid arguments
>
> Application root must be the path to
>   the application to run in this server.
>   Must contain a valid app.yaml or
>   app.yml file.
>
> [A bunch of dev_appserver.py option
>   follow this]

What am I doing wrong? and as far as I can tell, I've correctly configured everything.

Comment: have you tried using the Launcher?

Comment: Ya I ended up using the launcher a while ago and it worked fine. It's bizarre that the command line way wasn't working.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
Adding python.exe in front of dev_appserver.py solved the problem for me.

`c:\Programme\Python27\python.exe C:\Programme\Google\AppEngineSDK\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py MoviesBwu\`

Answer (score 1):

Very basic example:

```
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/gae/test$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 10.10 \n \l
```

---

alfred@alfred-laptop:~/gae$ python --version
Python 2.6.6

---

```
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/gae$ pwd
/home/alfred/gae
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/gae$ ls -al
total 3444
drwxr-xr-x  4 alfred alfred    4096 2011-01-28 01:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 77 alfred alfred    4096 2011-01-28 01:23 ..
drwxr-xr-x  8 alfred alfred    4096 2010-12-16 00:06 google_appengine
-rw-r--r--  1 alfred alfred 3506301 2011-01-28 01:21 google_appengine_1.4.1.zip
drwxr-xr-x  2 alfred alfred    4096 2011-01-28 01:24 test
```

---

```
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/gae$ ls google_appengine_1.4.1.zip 
google_appengine_1.4.1.zip
```

---

```
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/gae/test$ cat app.yaml 
application: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.py
```

---

```
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/gae/test$ cat helloworld.py 
print 'Content-Type: text/plain'
print ''
print 'Hello, world!'
```

---

```
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/gae/google_appengine$ ./dev_appserver.py ~/gae/test/
/home/alfred/gae/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py:42: DeprecationWarning: the sha module is deprecated; use the hashlib module instead
  import sha
/home/alfred/gae/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_login.py:33: DeprecationWarning: the md5 module is deprecated; use hashlib instead
  import md5
INFO     2011-01-28 00:26:06,814 appengine_rpc.py:153] Server: appengine.google.com
INFO     2011-01-28 00:26:06,819 appcfg.py:414] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2011-01-28 00:26:07,014 appcfg.py:428] The SDK is up to date.
WARNING  2011-01-28 00:26:07,015 datastore_file_stub.py:573] Could not read datastore data from /tmp/dev_appserver.datastore
INFO     2011-01-28 00:26:07,047 dev_appserver_main.py:485] Running application helloworld on port 8080: http://localhost:8080
```

---

```
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/gae/test$ curl http://localhost:8080/
Hello, world!
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error message, even after calling dev_appserver.py from two directories above my app.

Comment: you should have to same directory structure. Do exactly as I did, and if still failing, tjen something is definitely wrong and I can't help you!

Comment: I have the same directory structure, but on Windows 7. Any tips for what I should be checking for?

Comment: Oops I  missed the part about windows 7. But I think you are using `dev_appserver.py` wrong. Let's say you have the two files `helloworld.py` and `app.yaml` inside folder `c:\gae\hello`. Then you should invoke `python dev_appserver.py c:\gae\hello`. Else I am sorry, but I don't know :$

Comment: No problem, this is definitely a bit of an unusual issue.

Comment: it sure is. My advice is to just install ubuntu if you can't get it working. It is much better for doing web programming in my opinion. I only use linux nowadays :$

Comment: App Engine works fine on Windows.  "install a new OS because some random person on the internet can't help you" is the worst advice I've seen here ever.

Comment: It is the best advice I have given in a long time :P. *nix like OS are much better for programming! => http://antirez.com/post/linux-better-for-coding.html

Answer (score 0):

Select any **.py file** press alt + enter(**right mouse click -> properties**) select change then choose python.exe(application) for opening .py file from install directory and run your file... ;-p

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wvrx.png)